# How to add vertical line for below layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I want to add vertical line in below layout, but i am confuse how to add it. because my requirement is at the end of the vertcial line there is a button.

**My requirement is as per below image.**
[My requirement:show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvNrI.jpg)

I have attached my layout code and i am getting this output:
[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS3uO.jpg)

Please anyone help me to find out the solution.

**My Layout code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"

    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"

        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="20% OFF"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text="Max.Discount : $150" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/genre"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:text="Expiry on : 8 Nov 2017"
            android:textColor="@color/year" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maxdiscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="RAINY20"
            android:textColor="@color/year" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:text="Apply"
            android:layout_below="@+id/maxdiscount"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : Yes i Solved this .  I added vertical line view to the android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_apply"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found the solution. 
I added vertical line view with  `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"`

and

for down arrow button use the  `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/verticalline"` and  `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/verticalline"` properties. My problem solved. :)